# SQL Syntax on using OPENROWSET for reading a flat file

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a Text file, which i am using below syntax to read.

```
SELECT BulkColumn 
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\MyFolder\Priceflatfile.txt', SINGLE_CLOB) Myfile
```

Syntax returns multiple row of records in a single row in one column.

I have three column of multiple row of records. Is it possible to read the flat file in a SQL Syntax by displaying with table of records.

Comment: Why did you delete your setup question? It was going to be moved to another site (where it would be more on-topic *and* get better help), not merely closed and abandoned. Anyway, see [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqljourney/archive/2012/05/07/sql-2008-2008-r2-setup-disappears-fails-when-installing-setup-support-files.aspx) - and perhaps consider building a 2012 install with SP1 and the latest CU slipstreamed.

Comment: @AaronBertrand sorry for that. more than 4 people requested for close. i decided to delete.i can reopen it. still i am not able to install sql 2012 in my laptop

Comment: I read that blog. That blog was not helpful for Enterprise Edition. I followed the steps and tried to install. But it throws error on initial stage itself